# deploy to production from master or hotifx?

Tags: java, git, deployment, git-flow

We are adopting Git on the company after some years of SVN usage. The git flow suits our needs very well with the master/hotfix/develop/release branches. So far everything is going well, apart from a conundrum.
Our project is a Java app for weblogic, we produce a WAR file on the project build.

The context is:

- We have master as the trunk that holds code that goes to production
- A new hotfix is branched out of master
- Developers commit on hotfix
- QA tests hotfix
- A binary is approved QA-wise

The big question is:

- Should we deploy the binary from hotfix to production?
- Or should we merge to master, build from there, test and then deploy to production?

I understood that master would be the branch that would hold the code that goes to production. So I have an issue with deploying from hotfix.
However deploying from master would mean 2 QA cycles on the same codebase as the 2 builds (on hotfix and master) might produce different binaries depending on maven dependencies/build environment/...
And 2 QA cycles on the same codebase is a waste of resources.

I searched the web and found little reference about this. Here and there I see people saying they deploy from master, while others deploy from hotfix. The thing is that people who deploy from master usually are on a parsed language project (PHP, Perl, ...) so they don't have the binary to consider.

Does any of you faced this issue already? What approach did you take?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The point of branching out for a short-lived release branch for a small patch is that you can choose exactly what to apply to a known state. You might have a 1.0.0 release but you need a couple of bugfixes to make a 1.0.1. In that case branching from 1.0.0 and applying your bugfixes and releasing from there makes sense.

Merging from the release branch onto master and doing the release from there works too but begs the question of why you want to create the branch in the first place and whether this would actually be a hotfix. From a quality perspective it's probably better to develop on the target branch rather than work in isolation and do a final merge in the end – because just as you say you need two QA cycles.

The question to ask seems to be whether you want strict control of what commits to include in the new release or if you're good with any release that includes that set of commits.

It's not clear to me how the deployment type (uncompiled script languages vs. compiled languages) would be relevant to the discussion.

Comment: I noticed on the material I have seen on the web that due to the parsed nature of PHP/..., the difference of releasing from hotfix or master is none as the files will be the same in the server, but that is a longshot.
I see your point on developing on hotfix, is the same my team used here.
And about the question, I believe it is more a peace of mind thing than an actual issue. I want to ensure I can go back in history in 1 year time and be able to produce the build from master. As I haven't deployed from master though, my confidence in the master code is reduced. See what I mean?

Comment: Not really. Whether a build is reproducible one year later has nothing to do with which branch the release was made from, i.e. where the release's tag points. Either way it's just a commit. It doesn't even know which branch(es) it's a part of.

Answer (score -1):

this is an excellent post on git branching - hope this helps

Source : http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/
[image]

Comment: I'm familiar with this @dekdev, thanks! But you see on Tag 0.2 for instance. Is the potential binary pushed to production on the red hotfix commit right before merging to master or on master after merging? If on the hotfix, then why don't we tag the 0.2 at the hotfix rather than on master?

Comment: Actually, on the link I read: "Therefore, each time when changes are merged back into master, this is a new production release by definition. We tend to be very strict at this, so that theoretically, we could use a Git hook script to automatically build and roll-out our software to our production servers everytime there was a commit on master."

Comment: The diagram shows nothing about deployment; only branching and merging strategy, which the OP is not asking about.